# mutate and case_when: wrong numbers and NA

Tags: r, dplyr, case-when

so I have some trouble again with writing basically a Syntax.

```
w <- factor(c("m", "w", "w", "m", "m", "w", "w", "w", "m", "m"))
x <- c(28, 18, 25, 29, 21, 19, 27, 26, 31, 22)
y <- c(80, 55, 74, 101, 84, 74, 65, 56, 88, 78)
z <- c(170, 174, 183, 190, 185, 178, 169, 163, 189, 184)
bsp1 <- data.frame(w, x, y, z)
colnames(bsp1) <- c("Geschlecht", "Alter", "xx", "yy")
rm(w, x, y, z)
bsp1
```

I have this command, which actually used to work. (For the example it's not complete, but what I'm trying to do should be clear. Apparently, there is a problem with the 18:31 command.

```
bsp1 <- bsp1 %>%
  mutate(xxx =
           case_when(
             Geschlecht == "m" & Alter > 18 & xx == 55 ~ 1, 
             Geschlecht == "m" & Alter > 18 & xx == 56 ~ 2,
             Geschlecht == "m" & Alter > 18 & xx == 18:31 ~ 3,
             TRUE ~ NA_real_))
```

For whatever reason though, it now gives me a warning message (I need to roughly translate since my R Studio is set to german and I actually can't find this error message anywhere).
It still creates the xxx variable, though just some rows are being transformed while others, even with full information from the rest get assigned a "NA".

Warning message is (translated roughly from German):

```
Length of the longer vector is not a multiple of the shorter vector.
```

How can I rewrite the xx == 18:31 part, so it works?

Thank you in advance and sorry for the previous confusion.

Comment: can you show us these warnings?
Just type `warnings()` into the console

Comment: Try `xx %in% 18:31` instead. This is a frequent error, probably a duplicate. See the difference between the two following conditions `x <- rep(1:3, 2); x == 1:2; x %in% 1:2`.

Comment: I have just tried my suggestion in the comment above and it worked without errors or warnings.

Comment: Thank you! This solves the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```r
bsp1 %>%
  mutate(xxx =
           case_when(
             (Geschlecht == "w") & (Alter > 18) & (xx == 55) ~ "1", 
             (Geschlecht == "m") & (Alter > 18) & (xx == 56) ~ "2",
             TRUE ~ "NA_real_"))
```

Note that no elements meet the conditions, so you will all have all `NA_real_`

If you want a column with `NA` remove all double quotes:

```r
bsp1 %>%
  mutate(xxx =
           case_when(
             (Geschlecht == "w") & (Alter > 18) & (xx == 55) ~ 1, 
             (Geschlecht == "m") & (Alter > 18) & (xx == 56) ~ 2,
             TRUE ~ NA_real_))
```

Comment: When I type "TRUE ~ "NA_real_"", it gives the warning, that x must be a double vector, not a character vector. I know that for this example it would all be NA, but it would be a way to long list to write the whole code.

Comment: why did you write `"NA_real_"`? This is not the same as `NA`

Comment: Did you put double quotes at "1" and "2"? I tried with your dataset and my code works

Comment: Since I want the new created variable to be NA; when I only say NA, it gives the warning message, that x must be a double vector, not a character vector.

Comment: Sorry, already had to edit my question. There is not any quotation. The new variable should be numeric.

Comment: I edited my answer. Tell me if it works now